# value doesn't appear after filtering but it does in groupBy

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe `df` where one of the fields is `name` (string).

When I do:

```
df
.select("name")
.groupBy("name")
.count()
.show()
```

I get:

```
+--------------+-------+
|     name     | count |
+--------------+-------+
| Click event  |   120 |
| Show event   |    30 |
| Delete event |    12 |
| null         |    56 |
+--------------+-------+
```

However when I try:

```
df
.filter(col("name") === "Delete event")
.show()
```

it gives me an empty dataframe. It works properly for `Show event`.

I have tried trimming the column name (in case it has any spaces), lowering the characters, using `like` instead of `===`.

Interestingly when I filter the grouped database like that:

```
df
.select("name")
.groupBy("name")
.count()
.filter(col("name") === "Delete event")
.show()
```

it also works as expected.

Any idea why I might be experiencing that problem?

Comment: Do you have a code snippet how to create the data frame where this can be re-produced? Or is it only occurring using some special source?

Comment: I tried to create some minimal dataframe with just a few events to reproduce but I couldn't :(

Comment: The problem was related to our internal datasource and not Spark in general. Thanks.